# How to convert a dataframe to a 3D ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to convert a dataframe to a 3D np.array
I have tried df = df.as_matrix(). But it is a 2D matrix.
The Dataframe is df:

```
days                      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  20  21  \
enrollment_id event                                              ...           
1             access       0   0   3   0   0   0   0   8   0   4 ...  20   0   
              discussion   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   
              navigate     0   0   1   0   0   0   0   4   0   1 ...   0   0   
              page_close   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   6   0   2 ...  17   0   
              problem      0   0   8   0   0   0   0   6   0   0 ...   0   0   
              video        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...  14   0   
              wiki         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   
3             access       7   0   0   0   2   0   0  11   0   0 ...   0   0   
              discussion   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   
              navigate     4   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0 ...   0   0   
              page_close   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   0 ...   0   0   
              problem     14   0   0   0   0   0   0  13   0   0 ...   0   0   
              video        1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   
              wiki         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0
```

Comment: try to show toy examle: source data and what should happen. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066662/np-concatenate-a-nd-tensor-array-with-a-1d-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an array is just the bare values of the dataframe, simply do

```
arr = df.values
```

If the shape is not what you want, you can play around with the NumPy `reshape` method/function.

Comment: The df.values also return a 2D array. You mean usse NumPy reshape function to convert dataframe to 3D ndarray?

Comment: No, something like `arr = df.values.reshape((a, b, c))`, where `a`, `b` and `c` are the integer dimension sizes.