# np.concatenate a ND tensor/array with a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have two arrays a & b

```
a.shape
(5, 4, 3)
array([[[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.10772717,  0.604584  ,  0.41664413]],

       [[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.10772717,  0.604584  ,  0.41664413],
        [ 0.95879616,  0.85575133,  0.46135877]],

       [[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.10772717,  0.604584  ,  0.41664413],
        [ 0.95879616,  0.85575133,  0.46135877],
        [ 0.70442301,  0.74126523,  0.88965603]],

       [[ 0.10772717,  0.604584  ,  0.41664413],
        [ 0.95879616,  0.85575133,  0.46135877],
        [ 0.70442301,  0.74126523,  0.88965603],
        [ 0.8039435 ,  0.62802183,  0.58885027]],

       [[ 0.95879616,  0.85575133,  0.46135877],
        [ 0.70442301,  0.74126523,  0.88965603],
        [ 0.8039435 ,  0.62802183,  0.58885027],
        [ 0.95848603,  0.72429311,  0.71461332]]])
```

and b

```
array([ 0.79212707,  0.66629398,  0.58676553], dtype=float32)
b.shape
(3,)
```

I want to get array

```
ab.shape
(5,5,3)
```

I do as below
first

```
b = b.reshape(1,1,3)
```

then

```
b=np.concatenate((b, b,b, b, b), axis = 0)
```

And

```
ab=np.concatenate((a, b), axis = 1)
ab.shape
(5, 5, 3)
```

I get the right result, but it's not very convenient especially at the step

```
b=np.concatenate((b, b,b, b, b), axis = 0)
```

when I have to type many times (the real dataset has much dimensions). Are there any faster ways to come to this result?

Comment: `np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)), axis=1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.repeat`:

```
r = np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)), axis=1)
```

What this does, is first reshape your `b` array to match the dimensions of `a`, and then repeat its values as many times as needed according to `a`'s first axis:

```
b3D = b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)

array([[[1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3]]])

b3D.shape
(5, 1, 3)
```

This intermediate result is then concatenated with `a` -

```
r = np.concatenate((a, b3d), axis=0)

r.shape
(5, 5, 3)
```

This differs from your current answer mainly in the fact that the repetition of values is not hard-coded (i.e., it is taken care of by the repeat).

If you need to handle this for a different number of dimensions (not 3D arrays), then some changes are needed (mainly in how remove the hardcoded reshape of `b`).

---

**Timings**

```
a = np.random.randn(100, 99, 100)
b = np.random.randn(100)
```

```
# Tai's answer
%timeit np.insert(a, 4, b, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.7 ms per loop

# Divakar's answer
%%timeit 
b3D = np.broadcast_to(b,(a.shape[0],1,len(b)))
np.concatenate((a,b3D),axis=1)

100 loops, best of 3: 3.67 ms per loop

# solution in this post
%timeit np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)), axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.62 ms per loop
```

These are all pretty competitive solutions. However, note that performance depends on your actual data, so make sure you test things first!

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know whether the answer is wrong. I'll remove it if needed.

Comment: `np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)), axis=1)` that's the simpliest way as i can see

Comment: @Edward Sorry for the terse answer. Added an explanation if it helps.

Comment: @Edward, I've also added timings. Make sure you test all solutions on your data if you're worried about performance. Happy coding.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes, I noticed!

Answer (score 4):

Simply broadcast `b` to `3D` and then concatenate along second axis -

```
b3D = np.broadcast_to(b,(a.shape[0],1,len(b)))
out = np.concatenate((a,b3D),axis=1)
```

The `broadcasting` part with `np.broadcast_to` doesn't actual replicate or make copies and is simply a replicated view and then in the next step, we do the concatenation that does the replication on-the-fly.

### Benchmarking

We are comparing [`np.repeat` version from @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48066790/) against `np.broadcast_to` one 
 in this section with focus on performance. The broadcasting based one does the replication and concatenation in the second step, as a *merged command* so to speak, while `np.repeat` version makes copy and then concatenates in two separate steps.

**Timing the approaches as whole :**

Case #1 : `a = (500,400,300)` and `b = (300,)`

```
In [321]: a = np.random.rand(500,400,300)

In [322]: b = np.random.rand(300)

In [323]: %%timeit
     ...: b3D = b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)
     ...: r = np.concatenate((a, b3D), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 72.1 ms per loop

In [325]: %%timeit
     ...: b3D = np.broadcast_to(b,(a.shape[0],1,len(b)))
     ...: out = np.concatenate((a,b3D),axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 72.5 ms per loop
```

For smaller input shapes, call to `np.broadcast_to` would take a bit longer than `np.repeat` given the work needed for setting up the broadcasting is apparently more complicated, as the timings suggest below :

```
In [360]: a = np.random.rand(5,4,3)

In [361]: b = np.random.rand(3)

In [366]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(b,(a.shape[0],1,len(b)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.12 µs per loop

In [367]: %timeit b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 957 ns per loop
```

But, the broadcasting part would have a constant time irrepective of the shapes of the inputs, i.e. the `3 u-sec` part would stay around that mark. The timing for the counterpart : `b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)` would depend on the input shapes. So, let's dig deeper and see how the concatenation steps for the two approaches fair/behave.

**Diging deeper**

Trying to dig deeper to see how much the concatenation part is consuming :

```
In [353]: a = np.random.rand(500,400,300)

In [354]: b = np.random.rand(300)

In [355]: b3D = np.broadcast_to(b,(a.shape[0],1,len(b)))

In [356]: %timeit np.concatenate((a,b3D),axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 72 ms per loop

In [357]: b3D = b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)

In [358]: %timeit np.concatenate((a,b3D),axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 72 ms per loop
```

Conclusion : Doesn't seem too different.

Now, let's try a case where the replication needed for `b` is a bigger number and `b` has noticeably high number of elements as well.

```
In [344]: a = np.random.rand(10000, 10, 1000)

In [345]: b = np.random.rand(1000)

In [346]: b3D = np.broadcast_to(b,(a.shape[0],1,len(b)))

In [347]: %timeit np.concatenate((a,b3D),axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop

In [348]: b3D = b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)

In [349]: %timeit np.concatenate((a,b3D),axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 141 ms per loop
```

Conclusion : Seems like the merged concatenate+replication with `np.broadcast_to` is doing a bit better here.

Let's try the original case of `(5,4,3)` shape :

```
In [360]: a = np.random.rand(5,4,3)

In [361]: b = np.random.rand(3)

In [362]: b3D = np.broadcast_to(b,(a.shape[0],1,len(b)))

In [363]: %timeit np.concatenate((a,b3D),axis=1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 948 ns per loop

In [364]: b3D = b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)

In [365]: %timeit np.concatenate((a,b3D),axis=1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 950 ns per loop
```

Conclusion : Again, not too different.

So, the final conclusion is that if there are a lot of elements in `b` and if the first axis of `a` is also a big number (as the replication number is that one), `np.broadcast_to` would be a good option, otherwise `np.repeat` based version takes care of the other cases pretty well.

Comment: Even if the broadcast is cheaper, the subsequent concatenation will still need the new array to be created, so that should be timed as well...

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the timings myself, since I seem to be getting more downvotes than I'd like ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sorry about the downvotes. Hope those are not influenced by me or this post :)

Comment: Even if they are, I wouldn't hold it against you. Cheers, hope to see you in the next one!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some simple timings based on cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's and Divakar's solutions:

```
%timeit np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)), axis=1)
```

Output:
The slowest run took 6.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.68 µs per loop

```
%timeit np.concatenate((a, np.broadcast_to(b[None,None], (a.shape[0], 1, len(b)))), axis=1)
```

Output:
The slowest run took 4.12 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 µs per loop

Now here is the timing based on your original code:

```
%timeit original_func(a, b)
```

Output:
The slowest run took 4.62 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.69 µs per loop

Since the question asked for faster ways to come up with the same result, I would go for cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution based on these problem calculations.

Comment: Cheers, but I would highly recommend testing this on sample data of size a.shape = (500, 499, 3), for example.

Comment: Absolutely -- needs to scale!

Comment: The “this could mean that an intermediate result is being cached” is part of the output from the timeit function in ipython.

Comment: @RobertMilletich Got you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`np.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html).

```
b_broad = np.expand_dims(b, axis=0) # b_broad.shape = (1, 3)
ab = np.insert(a, 4, b_broad, axis=1)
""" 
Because now we are inserting along axis 1
     a'shape without axis 1 = (5, 3) 
     b_broad's shape          (1, 3)  
can be aligned and broadcast b_broad to (5, 3)
"""
```

In this example, we insert along the axis 1, and will put `b_broad` before the index given, 4 here. In other words, the `b_broad` will occupy index 4 at long the axis and make `ab.shape` equal `(5, 5, 3)`.

**Note** again that before we do insertion, we turn `b` into `b_broad` for **safely** achieve the right broadcasting you want. The dimension of `b` is smaller and there will be broadcasting at insertion. We can use `expand_dims` to achieve this goal.

If `a` is of shape `(3, 4, 5)`, you will need `b_broad` to have shape `(3, 1)` to match up dimensions if inserting along axis 1. This can be achieved by

```
b_broad = np.expand_dims(b, axis=1)  # shape = (3, 1)
```

It would be a good practice to make `b_broad` in a right shape because you might have `a.shape = (3, 4, 3)` and you really need to specify which way to broadcast in this case!

**Timing Results**

From OP's dataset: COLDSPEED's answer is 3 times faster.

```
def Divakar():  # Divakar's answer
    b3D = b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)
    r = np.concatenate((a, b3D), axis=1)
# COLDSPEED's result
%timeit np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)), axis=1)
2.95 µs ± 164 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# Divakar's result
%timeit Divakar()
3.03 µs ± 173 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# Mine's
%timeit np.insert(a, 4, b, axis=1)
10.1 µs ± 220 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Dataset 2 (Borrow the timing experiment from COLDSPEED): nothing can be concluded in this case because they share nearly the same mean and standard deviation.

```
a = np.random.randn(100, 99, 100)
b = np.random.randn(100)

# COLDSPEED's result
%timeit np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(a.shape[0], axis=0)), axis=1) 
2.37 ms ± 194 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# Divakar's
%timeit Divakar()
2.31 ms ± 249 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# Mine's
%timeit np.insert(a, 99, b, axis=1) 
2.34 ms ± 154 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Speed will depend on data's size, shape, and volume. Please tested on you dataset if speed is your concern.

Comment: This option appears simple. But I'm worried about efficiency. Interestingly, for OP's sample data, this is the slowest. May change for different sized inputs though.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This question is not too much about efficiency but readability. It shall depend on the size of data, I think. The method is reasonable fast tested on my computer: 10.1 µs ± 220 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each) Your methods is roughly 3 times faster than mine on my computer. But yes...it depends on the size of data...