# Numpy: how to insert an (N,) dimensional vector to an (N, M, D) dimensional array as new elements along the D axis? (N, M, D+1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

`a` is an array of shape `(N, M, D) == (20, 4096, 6)`.

`b` is an array of shape `(N,) == (20,)`.

I would like to insert the values of `b` to `a` such that each value in `b` is appended element-wise to the `D` dim in `a` (7th element in `a`).

So `c` would be such an array, of shape `(20, 4096, 7)`, where `c[i,:,-1] == b[i]` for all `i`, and `c[...,:-1] == a`.

I know you could just make a new array and add the values accordingly eg:

```
N, M, D = a.shape # (20, 4096, 6)
c = np.zeros((N, M, D+1))
c[...,:-1] = a
for i in range(N):
    c[i,:,-1] = b[i]
```

But was wondering if one of the numpy wizards here had a more slick way of doing this with numpy ops and no intermediate arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [np.concatenate a ND tensor/array with a 1D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066662/np-concatenate-a-nd-tensor-array-with-a-1d-array)

Comment: I don't see any intermediate arrays in your solution.  The desired result is larger than the original, so it has to be a new array.  Creating `c` and then filling it with `a` and `b` is a perfectly good solution. You just need to streamline the `b` assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicate `b` along the second axis after extending it to `3D` and then concatenate with `a` along the last axis -

```
b_rep = np.repeat(b[:,None,None],a.shape[1],axis=1)
out = np.concatenate((a, b_rep,axis=-1)
```

Alternatively, we can use `np.broadcast_to` to create the replicated version :

```
b_rep = np.broadcast_to(b[:,None,None], (len(b), a.shape[1],1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I guess there is no way to do just directly append_at the vector elementwise along some axis? You always have to broadcast?

Comment: @Alnitak Nope, no direct way there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one-liner

```
np.r_['2,3,0', a, np.broadcast_to(b, (a.T.shape[1:])).T]
```

Also, I'd like to mention that your original method is actually close to the (or at least a) recommended way. Just use `empty` instead of `zeros` and broadcasting instead of the loop:

```
res = np.empty((N,M,D+1), np.promote_types(a.dtype, b.dtype))
res[..., :-1], res[..., -1] = a, b[:, None]
```

...

And - just for fun - one more, which I expressly do not recommend. *Do not use this!*

```
np.where(np.arange(D+1)<D, np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (N,M,D+1), a.strides), b[:, None, None])
```